# convert .img to .vmdk using VBoxmanage

Tags: vmware-converter

Can Someone tell me how to convert .img to .vmdk using VBoxManage?
And also how to configure files .vmx etc which are needed to test this converted image on virtualbox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

in linux~

> VBoxManage convertdd  file.img file.vdi

in windows~

> open cmd.exe (Start > Run, enter: cmd.exe), navigate to your virtualbox install folder (using the "cd" command), then run this (after placing the .img file inside the virtualbox install folder (blahblah\program files\virtualbox\ or similar))
>
> > VBoxManage.exe convertdd file.img file.vdi

For the rest of your question, I noticed you asked about editing the .vmx file for Virtualbox? But I think .vmx files are for VMWare lol but either way this youtube video may be of help.

> www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1H0joFz_QM

Comment: How about macOS?